# Unable to perfom LINQ on this XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have an XML file. I am unable to perform any XLINQ query on this XML.

I also used [LINQPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad) to test, but it is not returning any result.

Sample query:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"G:\Plugins.xml");
var res = from plugin in doc.Descendants("Modules")
          select plugin;
res.Dump();
```

And the XML file is:

```
<SolutionProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/pag/cab-profile">
    <Modules>
        <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="xxxx.dll" />
        <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="xxxx.dll" />
        <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="xxxx.dll" />
        <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="xxxxx.dll" />
        <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="xxxxx.dll" />

        <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="xxxxxx.dll" />
    </Modules>
</SolutionProfile>
```

This is a SCSF and CAB XML file. If I remove the following tag from the XML query works fine.

```
<SolutionProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/pag/cab-profile">
</SolutionProfile>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [My linq-query doesn't work when adding the xmlns-attribute to the root-element in my XML-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793580/my-linq-query-doesnt-work-when-adding-the-xmlns-attribute-to-the-root-element-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with your SolutionProfile tags, but rather the presence of the xmlns attribute in it.

Duplicate of an existing SO question. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793580/my-linq-query-doesnt-work-when-adding-the-xmlns-attribute-to-the-root-element-in) for the exact answer.

Oh, and you'll be needing an extra "/" on the end of your namespace if you follow the solution in the link.