# How to query this attribute value with Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a XML document that's in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:blah:-myXSD-2007-03-14T00-26-45" solutionVersion="1.0" productVersion="15.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="http://blah/FormServerTemplates/blah.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.4"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2007-03-14T00:26:45" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">
    <my:workDay>MON-FRI</my:workDay>
</my:myFields>
```

I tried to query the `workday` with the following code but got `null`.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);

var workDay = from x in xdoc.Descendants("workDay")
              select x.Value;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My linq-query doesn't work when adding the xmlns-attribute to the root-element in my XML-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793580/my-linq-query-doesnt-work-when-adding-the-xmlns-attribute-to-the-root-element-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to include the namespace for `my:`:

```
 var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
 XNamespace myNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2007-03-14T00:26:45";

 var workDay = from x in xdoc.Descendants(myNamespace + "workDay")
               select x.Value;
```